# How to check if SQL Server 2008R2 merge pull subscription is set to reinitialize?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, merge-replication

I am using RMO and some T-SQL to manage my subscriptions and have a need to know if a subscription has been set to reinitialize on next sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can query the table sysmergesubscriptions on the server and check the column sentgen for your subscriber. If it is NULL, it has been marked for reinitialization.

Answer (score 0):

- Publisher: SQL Server 2016 Standard
- Subscriber: SQL Server 2012 Express
- Subscription Type: Merge Pull

The columns `schemaversion` & `schemaguid` are set to NULL when a subscription is marked for reinitialization. schemaversion is set to -1 when it's syncing after marked as reinitialization.

```
SELECT db_name, subscriber_server, schemaversion, schemaguid FROM sysmergesubscriptions
```